# Magento Wordpress Nginx Configuration

Tags: wordpress, magento, nginx

I have a Magento shop at http://example.com and I want to keep a Wordpress blog at http://example.com/blog.
I have installed the blog and everything seems to be fine but when am logging to Wp-Admin am getting 404 for css and js files due to which dashboard is looking very ugly.
Am I doing any mistake? am attaching my nginx config file

```
##################################################################################
#
#                       example.com
#
##################################################################################
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com ;
    #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/mebozo-magento.mebozo.com;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
        location /blog {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/mebozo-magento.mebozo.com/blog;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        rewrite ^.*/files/(.*) /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2;
        rewrite ^.*/wp-admin(.*) $1wp-admin/;


    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js)$
        {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html/mebozo-magento.mebozo.com/blog;
        rewrite ^/.*(/.*\.(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js))$ $1 last;

        rewrite ^.*/files/(/.*(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js))$/wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 last;

        expires 30d;
        break;
        }

## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally

#location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
#expires 1y;
#log_not_found off;
#}

        location ~ .php/ { 
        ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

################For Foomen Speedster###############
#rewrite ^/minify/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;
#    rewrite ^/skin/m/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;

#    location /lib/minify/ {
#        allow all;
#    }


error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

#############gzip###########

        gzip on; # use gzip compression
        gzip_min_length 1100;
        gzip_buffers 4 8k; 
        gzip_proxied any; # enable proxy for the fcgi requests
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/javascript application/json; 

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}
    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #

    location ~ \.php$ {
        #      if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss
        root           /usr/share/nginx/html/mebozo-magento.mebozo.com;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html/mebozo-magento.mebozo.com$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt to solve this puzzle by suggesting that we clean up your nginx config file. Your */files/ rewrites look to be problematic to me.

Without knowing what your nginx.conf file looks like OR what your http {block} looks like, I will assume that it is pretty clean and that you are handling your global settings like gzip types, ssl protocols and ciphers, and additional headers, etc. there. I know that you included your gzip on in your file but sometimes duplicate that in server not realizing it is already set a layer above... if not add your gzip back in as necessary. All that said, after reading your conf file completely and I would suggest rewriting it to something like this:

(Note: the new URI level location and the @rewrites, and the removal of redundant root path definitions.)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    ## SSL CONFIGURATION (can be done here in same file)
    #listen 443 ssl http2;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    #ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
    #ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/star_example.com.priv.key;

    # domain name
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # doc root
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/mebozo-magento.mebozo.com;

    ## Logs per vhost
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log warn;

    ## This can also be set in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Adjust upload max file size settings
    # This value should match your PHP.ini config settings for upload_max_filesize
    client_max_body_size 50M; # allows file uploads up to 50 megabytes

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    ## Main Magento location
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }

    # Your blog location
    location /blog/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite_blog;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root    /usr/share/nginx;
    }

    ## These locations are protected
    location ~ /(app|downloader|includes|pkginfo|var|errors/local.xml)/ {
        deny all;
    }

    ## Images
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        add_header ETag "";
    }

    location =/js/index.php/x.js {
        rewrite ^(.*\.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    # rewrites
    location @rewrite {
        rewrite / /index.php?$args;
    }

    location @rewrite_blog {
        rewrite /blog/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    }

    ## Execute PHP scripts
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        ## Store code with multi store/domain magento instance
        #fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $mage_code;
        #fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE $mage_type;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
    location ~* (\.php$|\.sh$|\.txt$|\.htaccess$|\.git|\.sample$|mage$) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```